# Add Null Argument to Python Partial

Tags: python, function, factory

I am Trying to emulate the following code with something more elegant:

```
def makeHomeFunc(axisNumber):
    def fClosure(null_pass):
        stage.home(axisNumber)
    return fClosure
```

In short this is a function factory, that acts like functools.partial with the additional property of discarding the values passed to the produced function, and running the inner wrapped function with the factory's call.

Thanks

Comment: That's not really `partial`, that's closer to `wraps`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. What is wrong with your current code? Why do you think there should be a better way?

Comment: Honestly, its a bit ugly and make and tosses some fake things just to unify an interface.  I have a paired lambda version that is similarly confusing.  "wraps" is interesting, I am going to look at it some more. . .